# deltaTime as a local variable on each object, or a single shared variable?

Tags: c#, timedelta

Lets say that I have a GameWorld with an Update() method. Besides my GameWorld I also have a GameObject class with an Update() method.

The GameWorld has 0..* instances of my GameObject class, and the Update() method inside GameWorld calls Update() on all GameObjects in my GameWorld.

I need to use deltaTime in each of my GameObjects, and this is my questions:
Would it be ok to create a deltaTime inside my GameWorld, and let all GameObjects go through GameWorld to get access to a deltaTime. This deltaTime will be updated inside the GameWorld's Update().

Or is it better to create a local deltaTime variable inside the GameObject class, so that each object has it's own deltaTime, and let Update() on each GameObject handle the deltaTime?

Are there any pros or cons for doing one or the other, or will it give me the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off with a `deltaTime` for each `GameObject`. If you have a significant number of objects and the calculations inside their `Update()` functions take a significant amount of time, the `deltaTime` of the `GameWorld` can differ from the actual elapsed time since the object's last update. Moreover, depending on the method you choose to implement your program, this difference in time can be different for every object, which may lead to additional complications.

For example, let's say you have two instances of `GameObject`. `GameWorld.Update()` is called and the `deltaTime` is calculated. Now, if the first object takes an unexpectedly long time to update, the second object will receive a `deltaTime` which is smaller than the actual time that elapsed since its last update. Additionally, in the next update, the first object will receive a `deltaTime` that is larger than the actual value.

In my opinion, you should go with something like this:

```
class GameObject
{
   DateTime lastUpdate;

   void Update()
   {
      TimeSpan deltaTime = DateTime.Now - lastUpdate;

      ...
   }
}
```

The overhead in computational cost and memory is negligible, and although a "static" implementation of `deltaTime` may be sufficient in most cases, the code above can save you from a lot of headache later.